# Apache POI - Working with XSSFWorkbok + servlet response

Tags: java, excel, servlets, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm having problems in my java application to enable downloading XLSX files.

following the example displayed in this link: [Create an excel file for users to download using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226603/create-an-excel-file-for-users-to-download-using-apache-poi-jsp), I tried two configurations to download/save a spreadsheet.

First with a .XLS file:

```
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testxls.xls");

HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Some text");

ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wb.write(outByteStream);

byte[] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write(outArray);
outStream.flush();
```

This works.

Then i tried with a XLSX file:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testxls.xlsx");

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("Some text");

ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wb.write(outByteStream);

byte[] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write(outArray);
outStream.flush();
```

When i try this, i receive the message: "**Excel found unreadable content in 'testxls.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? ....**"

Despite this message, the spreadsheet opens normally, but i really want to remove this message.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type is `outByteStream`?

Comment: Why do you need a `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Can't you simply do `wb.write(response.getOutputStream())` instead?

Comment: I tried with `org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream` and 
`java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`

Comment: Tried with `wb.write(response.getOutputStream())`, but the message persists.

Comment: Try this http://superuser.com/questions/401714/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-excel-found-unreadable-content-in-filename

Comment: If you write the XSSFWorkbook to a file rather than the servlet, can Excel open that without errors? That'll let you work out if you have a servlet output problem, or a XSSF problem

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old (6 years) but I made my way here after updating some old code to move from HSSF to XSSF, my issue was a missing jar xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar. The error was written to the TomCat localhost log "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject"

Answer (score 0):

`XSSFWprkbook` is `AutoCloseable` and its `close()` does some additional work.
Best use *try-with-resources* which ensures that close is always called event with exception or return inside the block.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Some text");
           
    wb.write(outByteStream);
}
byte[] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();

OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write(outArray);
outStream.flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this JSP code and generate the excel file succesfully.I have given input to excel file through the database you can also give manual inputs.

```
<%HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
       try {
        java.sql.Connection con;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/custinfo","root","abc");
            Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
            out.println("hello world");
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select name ,state ,balance,description from customerdata where customerid='"+Id+"'"); 

        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        row.createCell((short)0).setCellValue("NAME");
        row.createCell((short)1).setCellValue("STATE");
        row.createCell((short)2).setCellValue("BALANCE");
        row.createCell((short)3).setCellValue("DESCRIPTION");
        while(rs.next())
        {
             out.println("hello world data");       
            HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow((short)i);
            row1.createCell((short)0).setCellValue(rs.getString("name"));
            row1.createCell((short)1).setCellValue(rs.getString("state"));
         row1.createCell((short)2).setCellValue(rs.getString(3));
         row1.createCell((short)3).setCellValue(rs.getString(4));
         i=i+1;
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short)1); 

        }

       }
      catch(SQLException e) {
        out.println("SQLException caught: " +e.getMessage());
      }%>
    // create a small spreadsheet
    <%

    %>
    <% 

    ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wb.write(outByteStream);
    byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
    response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
    response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
    response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testxls.xls");
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(outArray);
    outStream.flush();

    %>
```

Comment: But this example is still HSSF, i.e. .xls, rather than XSSF for .xlsx as the OP wants. Can you highlight what's different here, and what you think makes the difference?

Comment: Based on [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23340734/243245) it looks like the important point is to set the content length.