# Groovy/Grails document download

Tags: excel, grails, apache-poi

I'm currently working on a web application using grails. One of the requirements is to generate excel timesheets and download it afterword.
This is my code for downloading from grails controller.

```
response.contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=name.xls")
response.outputStream << wb.bytes
response.outputStream.flush()
```

But my excel file is corrupted. I can open it using open office, but doesn't work using microsoft office or google drive. Looks like the content of the xls file is not well formatted.
If I save document instead of downloading everything is ok.

```
 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("name.xls")
 wb.write(fileOut)
 fileOut.close()
```

I cannot figured out why the file content is corrupted when downloaded as byte array.

Grails version - 2.3.7
   Apache poi version - 3.13

Thanks in advance,

Method code

```
   def generate(){

    TimeSheetExportWrapper timeSheet = new TimeSheetExportWrapper()
    bindData(timeSheet, params.ts)

    HSSFWorkbook wb = excelExportService.createExcelTimeSheet(getCurrentTenant(), timeSheet, getCurrentTimezone())

    response.contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=${timeSheet.proposedFileName}")
    response.outputStream << wb.bytes
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

Comment: Post your entire controller method. It might be something before/after what you have posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387243/apache-poi-working-with-xssfworkbok-servlet-response I have got it working using this method

Comment: There are a few things you should do. 1. Add the content length to the header, 2. close the outputStream `response.outputStream.close()` and 3. `return null` after you close the stream so Grails doesn't try and render any view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you should be doing:

First, set the content length: `response.setHeader("Content-Length", "${wb.bytes.length}")`

Secondly, close the output: `response.outputStream.close()`

And finally, make sure you `return null` to ensure Grails does not attempt to render a view.

```
   def generate(){

    TimeSheetExportWrapper timeSheet = new TimeSheetExportWrapper()
    bindData(timeSheet, params.ts)

    HSSFWorkbook wb = excelExportService.createExcelTimeSheet(getCurrentTenant(), timeSheet, getCurrentTimezone())

    response.contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", "${wb.bytes.length}")
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=${timeSheet.proposedFileName}")
    response.outputStream << wb.bytes
    response.outputStream.flush()
    response.outputStream.close()
    return null
}
```

Comment: Does this work with `XSSFWorkbook` instead of `HSSFWorkbook` too?