# PhpExcel - Can't open the downloaded file

Tags: php, phpexcel

[This guy seems to have the same problem as me but it's Java and I don't understand anything :/ [excel can not open the downloaded file through jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717680/excel-can-not-open-the-downloaded-file-through-jsp) ]
Hello everyone,

First of all, I want to say that English isn't my mother language so you might see some mistakes but I hope you will understand me.
So I'm a student and I have a 'student job', creating a website for a micro-bakery! They need to have a file with all their clients and I decided to use PhpExcel to generate it!

I did everything properly but it still doesn't work! I looked for help on google of course but nobody has the same error message as me. Here is what I get.

[Error message I get when I try to open the file : In english : "Impossible to open the file "....xlsx" because it's format or extension is not valid. Please verify that the file is not broken and that it's extension match the file format"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYYlZ.png)

The source code is here : `

```
if($action=="client-excel"){
    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');


    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once '../libs/phpExcel/PHPExcel.php';


    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("BakeryName")
                                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Clients")
                                                 ->setTitle("Liste Clients ")
                                                 ->setSubject("Liste Clients ")
                                                 ->setDescription("Liste Clients ")
                                                 ->setKeywords("Liste Clients ")
                                                 ->setCategory("Liste Clients");

                    $toSupp=array();

                        $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
                        $array=array();
                        $array['header'][]="#client";
                        $array['header'][]="Nom";
                        $array['header'][]="Mail";
                        $array['header'][]="Nombre de pain(s) acheté(s)";
                        $array['data']=array();

                        $list = Client::getAllClients($order="id_client",$letter="",$valid=false,$start=0,$limit=100000);                                                           foreach($list as $client){
                            $client_array=array(
                                $client->getId(),
                                $client->getName(),
                                $client->getEmail(),
                                $client->getNbPainsCmd(),

                                );
                            $array['data'][]=$client_array;
                        }
                        if(sizeof($array['data'])==0){
                            $toSupp = $z;
                        }

                        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

                        $j=0;
                        foreach($array['header'] as $h){
                            $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
                            $objRichText->createTextRun($h)->getFont()->setBold(true);
                             $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow ($j,1,  $objRichText);
                            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn($j)->setAutoSize(true);
                            $j++;
                        }

                        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array['data']);$i++){
                            for($j=0;$j<sizeof($array['data'][$i]);$j++){
                            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow ($j,$i+2, $array['data'][$i][$j]);
                            }
                        }                       
                        // Rename worksheet
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Liste clients");

                    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
                    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="filename.xlsx"');
                    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

                        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

                        header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
                    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
                    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
                    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

                    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
                    $objWriter->save('php://output');
                    exit;

                }`
```

Thank you very much for all your potential answers!

Comment: Open the file in a text editor, and look for any leading/trailing whitespace characters, BOM header, or any plaintext messages/html markup or similar... that will help to identify the problem

Comment: Though I'm intrigued by why you're using a rich text object for setting the headers to bold when you could simply set the cell style to bold

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting me to do :s Sorry and thanks for the help!

Comment: Instead of opening the file in MS Excel; open it in a text editor, like the editor you use to write your PHP scripts, or Windows Notepad.... and look to see if the file contains any PHP error messages

Comment: Nope, just some random characters like this one : œ72ØÅŸRi«ÓúÓJÀØ¾¥U