# how can i download an excel file from server side to client side using jsp servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am implementing a web application where I need to download database data into excel. I retrieve all the data into excel, and save on the server side, but how can I download that excel into client side?

I have done this code:

```
row = spreadsheet.createRow(p);
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(m);
cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue(emp_code);
cell = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellValue(card_no);
// ... more code

String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
File    path = new File(root + "/Downloads/ExcellFile");
f="/salary_Report.xls";
String n=path+f;
System.out.println(" File name"+f);
if (!path.exists()) {
    boolean status = path.mkdirs();
}

FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(path+f));
workbook.write(output);
output.close();
```

After that what I will do to download that excel file?

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-to-download-document-files-from-webserver-using-servlet/28369

Comment: Instead of writing it to a file on the server's file system you should write to the response's outputstream.

Comment: https://www.addontechnologies.net/knowledge-base/how-to-make-xlsx-file-using-java-and-download-that-file.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an excel file for users to download using Apache POI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226603/create-an-excel-file-for-users-to-download-using-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ExcelService` class with a method like this, which is universal. This method can be used either for writing to a file (which is useful for testing and if you need to *store* the files on the server side), or using this method you may later write to the output stream of your servlet.

Also notice that each method is responsible for [closing the resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (and just that resource) which it has opened - `writeToXlsx(OutputStream)` for the `Workbook`, `writeToXlsx(String)` for the `OutputStream`.

```
/**
 * Create an Excel file (as OutputStream) with your data
 * 
 * @param output The OutputStream to which the method should write. 
 *        It must be opened before!
 *        Notice that although it is an <em>output</em> of the method,
 *        it is provided as an <em>input</em> parameter.
 *        The idea is: "Give me the data, and here is the place 
 *        you should put them to."
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void writeToXlsx(OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    try (final Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();) {
        final Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet(...);
        // your code here to fill the sheet
        wb.write(output);
    }
}
```

For your convenience (and testing), you may create a specific method which writes to a file. However this is *not* the method to be used by your client application!

```
/**
 * Create an Excel file (as file) with your data.
 * 
 * @param outputFile The name of the output file.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void writeToXlsx(String outputFile) throws IOException {
    try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile))) {
        writeToXlsx(output);
    }
}
```

Your servlet may look like this. It uses the service you have created.

```
@WebServlet("/content/data")
public class DataServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = ....;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        writeHeader(response);
        writeBody(response);
    }

    private void writeBody(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Each servlet has the output stream which is directly 
        // streamed to the client browser as the response:
        final OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

        // Now your service creates the data and writes them to the 
        // output stream:
        final ExcelService service = new ExcelService();
        service.writeToXlsx(output);

        // To be sure that nothing is lost:
        output.flush();
    }

    private void writeHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
        // Here you tell the browser that the result is not HTML, but Excel.
        // The browser uses this information to open an application
        // associated in the client operating system with this type
        // of data.
        response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");

        // The browser will pass this information to Excel
        // which will consider this as the file name
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyData.xlsx");
    }    
}
```